# Significance of Target in detaching a Thread in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have recently started getting acquainted with explicit Multithreading in swift. I am trying to understand the below method to dispatch a new thread for executing a selector. while I am able to use it successfully, what I don't understand is what is the significance of `target` in the signature of the method below? is that argument used to hold a monitor lock for thread safety like in java ? I tried referring to the documentation with not much help. I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand what's happening under the hood here.

```
(void)detachNewThreadSelector:(SEL)selector 
                   toTarget:(id)target 
                 withObject:(id)argument;
```

Comment: If you are asking about Swift, why did you post the Objective-C signature of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `aTarget` says:

> The object that will receive the message aSelector on the new thread.

This means that the selector will be called on the object that you pass as the target. It's no different than making any other method call. You call a method on a specific instance of a class. The target is the specific instance. The selector is the method that is called on that instance.

Comment: so, if i dispatch multiple threads invoking same selector on the same instance as target, multiple threads would execute the method on exact same instance ?

Answer (score 1):

Think of `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` as calling the given method of the given object, with the given argument (or ignore the argument if the method has zero parameters), but call the method on a newly created thread.

For example:

```c
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(expensiveComputationWithObjects:)
                           target:someCalculatorObject
                       withObject:someVeryLargeArray]
```

The method thus provides a very convenient way of dispatching method calls on background threads (though it doesn't allow reusing an existing thread).

Another minor disadvantage is that the methods in discussions need to have at most one parameter, though this limitation can be circumvented by having the target method receive a structure (a dictionary or another class) that holds the actual arguments.

Comment: can you recommend a workaround for being able to send multiple arguments?

Comment: @Harshal I updated the answer and added a workaround for that.